# Automatically update layers in GeoServer

Tags: layer, geoserver

I am working using the OpenGeo Suite program on Windows, to create a live map that updates when changes are made to the PostGIS table the layer is based on. However, this is not possible to do unless the layer is reloaded back into the GeoServer. Is there any way of making this process automatic. Thanks

Comment: Are you using OpenLayers to make your 'Live Map'. If so won't a layer redraw just rerequest the tiles from GeoServer, which should be Live as long as they are not going into your GeoWebCache. Or have I got the wrong end of the stick here

Comment: Just realized how old this question was! Did you get a solution?

Comment: And I've just realsied how long since you replied. No solution was found unfortunatly in the time frame i had. But thanks for the reply

Comment: Reload layers programmatically using REST, http://blog.opengeo.org/2012/10/25/adding-layers-to-geoserver-using-the-rest-api/